# How to suppress `ffmpeg` output logging when using H.265 codec in quiet mode

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

When I run:-

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -i "${INPUT}" -c:v libx265 -crf 23 "${OUTPUT}"
```

I'm still getting output from the command even though the `loglevel` is set to `silent` (see the example of the output below)

```
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.5+20-17839cc0d
x265 [info]: build info [Mac OS X][clang 11.0.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-3 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 2 / wpp(9 rows)
x265 [warning]: Source height < 720p; disabling lookahead-slices
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-23.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvp
x265 [info]: tools: b-intra strong-intra-smoothing deblock sao
```

I'm using `v5` of `ffmpeg`

```
ffmpeg version 5.0-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
```

How do I get `ffmpeg` to be really quiet?

Answer (score 6):

Add `-x265-params log-level=none`.